# Geocoding Service using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, geocoding

I am new to angular js.   How can I implement geocoding services?  Specifically, when I fill in a full address, how can I then populate the other fields (`postal code,city,country,lat and lng`) automatically?

I want to achieve something like [this page](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2012/05/faster-address-entry-with-google-places.html) in angular.
Please help me out.

I have code to populate the full address:

```
app.directive('googlePlaces', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        // transclude:true,
        scope: {location:'='},
        template: '<input type="text" id="fulladdress" name="fulladdress" ng-model="enterprise.fulladdress" class="form-control text-field" placeholder="">',
        link: function($scope, elm, attrs){
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#country")[0], {});
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                $scope.location = place.geometry.location.lat() + ',' + place.geometry.location.lng();
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group enterprise-form">
     <label>Full Address</label>
     <google-places location=location></google-places>
</div>
```

I want to populate two or three more fields `lat,lng, postal code`. Can I extend my directive to achieve this, and if so how?

Comment: You should perhaps try something and see how far you get, then come back and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: You can't ask to write code for you (from scratch), you will not receive any answer, because this is not a question.

Comment: okay thanks.. i just added my code above by which i get only address. But i want some things more on the behalf on address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just follow the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

The autocomplete listener `'place_change'` happens outside of angular's $digest loop so you should call `fillInAddress` using `$evalAsync` or you won't see your form change until the next digest.

The latitude, longitude is stored on the `place` object in `geometry.location`.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  var components = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {
    types: ['geocode']
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    $scope.$evalAsync(fillInAddress);
  });
  
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.ll = {};

  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    Object.keys(components).forEach(function(component) {
      $scope.formData[component] = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    });
    
    place.address_components.forEach(function(component) {
      var addressType = component.types[0];
      if (components[addressType]) {
        $scope.formData[addressType] = component[components[addressType]];
      }
    });
    $scope.ll = {
      lat: place.geometry.location.G,
      lon: place.geometry.location.K
    };
  }
});
```

```css
#locationField,
#controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}
#autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99%;
}
.label {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  color: #303030;
}
#address {
  border: 1px solid #000090;
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
  width: 480px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
#address td {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.field {
  width: 99%;
}
.slimField {
  width: 80px;
}
.wideField {
  width: 200px;
}
#locationField {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text">
  </div>
  <table id="address">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Street address</td>
      <td class="slimField">
        <input ng-model="formData.street_number" class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" type="text">
      </td>
      <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
        <input ng-model="formData.route" class="field" id="route" disabled="true">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">City</td>
      <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
        <input ng-model="formData.locality" class="field" id="locality" disabled="true">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">State</td>
      <td class="slimField">
        <input ng-model="formData.administrative_area_level_1" class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
      </td>
      <td class="label">Zip code</td>
      <td class="wideField">
        <input ng-model="formData.postal_code" class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Country</td>
      <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
        <input ng-model="formData.country" class="field" id="country" disabled="true">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <pre>{{ formData | json }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ ll | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dting how can I change the ng-model= "formData.locality" to "formData.city" ?